# How to use cpio to modify or creat ramdisk?

Tags: android, linux, cygwin

This question contain 2 parts.New is at line 29.

I use cygwin cpio command to creat ramdisk.But i find it cant used in android becouse file tree is E:\xx\xx.
I need ramdisk content is \xx.How to do?

```
set "bin=E:\cygwin64\bin"
set "PATH=E:"
"%bin%"\find "%PATH%"\ramdisk -depth -print0 | "%bin%"\cpio --null -ov >e:\ramdisknew
```

when i use cpio -t the output like this.

```
E:\ramdisk/acct
E:\ramdisk/bugreports
E:\ramdisk/cache
E:\ramdisk/charger
E:\ramdisk/config
E:\ramdisk/d
E:\ramdisk/data
```

I need -t putput like this.

```
"E:\cygwin64\bin"\cpio -t "E:"\ramdisk0
acct
bugreports
cache
charger
config
d
```

### data

I found in windows the file or dirctory Owner is 1000 not root maybe thats the problem.

So i changed Fedora 31.

The origin file ramdisk0 properties Kind=CPIO archive.

Use cpio -idv < /ramdisk0 then -ov to ramdisknew.Replace origin ramdisk0 to run android

It DONT work.

I find two problem

1.Output sequence become reverse not [acct bugreports cache d]

```
selinux_version
sepolicy
init.environ.rc
init.zygote32.rc
etc
config
```

2.ramdisknew hex content differ from ramdisk0
Origin ramdisk0 includ lot of '07070100049...' but ramdisknew have none
The only string 'acct' is a dir still in format

[070701000493e0000041ed0000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000500000000acct]

but in ramdisknew the format is[...Õ^Gð....acct]

origin ramdisk hex [part]

```
...
30 30 00 00  30 37 30 37  30 31 30 30  30 34 39 33 | 00..070701000493
65 31 30 30  30 30 61 31  61 34 30 30  30 30 30 30 | e10000a1a4000000
30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 | 0000000000000000
30 31 30 30  30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 | 0100000000000000
33 32 30 30  30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 | 3200000000000000
30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 | 0000000000000000
30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 | 000000000b000000
30 30 62 75  67 72 65 70  6F 72 74 73  00 00 00 00 | 00bugreports.... 
2F 64 61 74  61 2F 75 73  65 72 5F 64  65 2F 30 2F | /data/user_de/0/com
...
```

new ramdisknew hex [part]

```
D5 5E 47 F0  0B 00 00 00  32 00 62 75  67 72 65 70 | Õ^Gð....2. bugrep
6F 72 74 73  00 00 2F 64  61 74 61 2F  75 73 65 72 | orts../data/user_de/0/com
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Why do you expect Android to have the Windows file structure ? `cpio` is only copying data  surely not creating a RAMDISK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe something like this might work:

```
pushd "%PATH%"\ramdisk
"%bin%"\find . -depth -printf "%P\0" | "%bin%"\cpio --null -ov >e:\ramdisknew
popd
```

Cpio here apparently stores the full path as passed by Find.  The `pushd` and `popd` commands temporarily change the working directory to where the files are stored.  The `find` command is modified to look into the current directory (but that change isn't strictly necessary) and to print only the relative path (the `%P`); null character separators are retained (the `\0` part).

Comment: "E:\cygwin64\bin"\find . -depth -printf "P\0" output
P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P PP P P P

Comment: Note the percent sign (%P).